# Interesting upvoting patterns, upvotes on inactive answers after renewed general activity

Tags: discussion

Recently I answered questions in stackoverflow and math.SE after some period of inactivity. Practically immediately I got upvotes on my other answers in these sites. Is this normal upvoting pattern, i.e. encouragement from the community? I admit I did this for some new users in stats.SE which is my main site, but only because their other answers were really good, and the intention was to get their reputation of the ground, so they get basic privileges, such as commenting.

Feel free to close this if it is too off-topic.

Comment: I noticed it as well. And occasionally I link to an earlier answer of mine (if I think it's usefull) and that too usually leads to a few upvotes on that answer.

Comment: @Joachim, yes if the link to old answer is present in active question, then it is natural. In my case the answers were not of the active questions and there were no links, so someone had to go to my profile, select answer and then upvote it, which is a bit too dedicated behaviour IMHO. The odd thing that it happened in two different sites. Not that I am complaining, just curious.

Comment: @mpiktas how can you be sure this happened?

Comment: @jzd, just picking the likeliest explanation. I assume you were asking about going to my profile page and voting up the questions.

Comment: @mpiktas, yes I was.  This is an explanation but is not the only one.

Comment: @jzd, yes I know, that is why I asked the question :)

Comment: @mpiktas, I guess I misunderstood the question.  Are you asking about a specific case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can happen that an old answer you gave is up-voted simply because there is a recent question that links to the old one, for example because the recent question has been closed as duplicate of the other question, or because who asked the recent question linked it to the other question.

I would say it's not a common practice that somebody who reads your answer starts to vote your other answers, simply for the fact SE sites detect consecutive votes done from a user to the same user, when they happen in a short period of time. What happens in these cases is that the votes will be removed from the system; if I remember well, that normally happens at midnight UTC.